# link_to with :action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an link to the show action but I want it to go to the "edit" action

```
<%= link_to("Previous Post", @line.previous) if @line.previous %>
```

how do I change this to go to "edit" rather than "show"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following. There are more examples at [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

```
link_to "Previous Post", :controller => "profiles", :action => "edit", :id => @profile

# => <a href="/profiles/edit/1">Previous Post</a>
```